# Read json and create table javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am am trying to read json data and import it to my table in html. 
But some how it is not working.

I have already implemented a function to type in data what works great.

Only the function to load the json data is not working.

But i really don't know why.

I have posted the whole html code and my load data function.
MY Javascript code:

```
function loadData() {

var text = '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"Ben","lastName":"dsafsad" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"dsdsaadsj" },' +
'{"firstName":"Jules","lastName":"MIAU" }]}';

obj = JSON.parse(text);

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {     
var currentObj = obj[i];
var myName = currentObj.employees[0].firstName;
var age = currentObj.employees[0].lastName;
var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age.value;

}
}
```

MY HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML dynamic table using JavaScript</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="myform">
<b>Simple form with name and age ...</b>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Age:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="age">
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()">
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Load Data" onclick="Javascript:loadData()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="mydata">
<b>Current data in the system ...</b>
<table id="myTableData"  border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Age</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
&nbsp;<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense: `for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {     
var currentObj = json[i];`.  Your json is in a variable called `text` which is then parsed to an object called `obj`.  What is `json`?

Comment: @devlincarnate yes you are right it should be obj.length it was a part of my old code sorry. but still it is not working but i don't know why maybe you have an idear ?

Comment: What is the `value` property of a string value supposed to mean? After conversion of the string to a String object is will be undefined because there is no such property,

Comment: I made some changes in the code but still have the same error. What do you mean with the conversion of the string to a string ?

Comment: You have mentioned an error in comments, but I don't see the error in the question?

Comment: @Ben. If you refer to the property of a string, like `"sometext".value`, javascript converts "sometext" to a [String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) automatically so it can look for the property ".value". Since this property is not there, the result is undefined, *but no error will be shown on the console because it is permissible to try and access an object property which does not exist..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be iterating over obj.employees, not obj.  You have one object, which is composed of an employees array (with length of 3 in your example).

```
  obj = JSON.parse(text);
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(obj.length);  //this returns undefined
  console.log(obj.employees.length); //this is what you want
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.employees.length; i++) {
    var currentObj = obj.employees[i];
    console.log(currentObj);
    var myName = currentObj.firstName;
    console.log(myName);
    var age = currentObj.lastName;
    console.log(age);
  }
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1q2054ov/)

You also have a problem here:

```
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName.value;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age.value;
```

myName and age are variables you defined, not html elements, and as such, they don't have a value property.  You just need to refer to the variables themselves, like so:

```
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= myName;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= age;
```

[Update Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yyguv09m/1/)